# background effect on click / h3 with tag a

Tags: css

Hello I would like to know if it is possible to remove this background by clicking on mobile devices in my h3 tag with

code:

```
<Styled.CardTop background={TestBG2}>
      <div className="Bg" />
        <div className="headerH3">
        <h3 onMouseEnter={() => setHover(true)} onMouseLeave={() => setHover(false)}>
         <a href='xd'>aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa.</a>
        </h3>
        </div>
      </Styled.CardTop>
```

css:

```
const CardTop = styled.div`
  position: relative;
  height: 300px;
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom:40px;
  & .Bg {
    display:flex;
    align-items:center;
    position:relative;
    background-image: url(${({ background }) => background});
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    height: 200px;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
    cursor:pointer;
    :hover{
      box-shadow: inset 0 0 100px 100px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    }
}
  & .headerH3 {
    padding: 0 10px;
    display:flex;
    align-items:center;
    justify-content:center; 
    word-break: break-all;
  }
  & > div > h3 {
    text-align: left;
    font-size: 1rem !important;
    font-family: Roboto Slab, serif;
    font-weight: 700;
    margin: 10px 0px 10px 0 !important;
  }
  & > div > h3 > a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color:#1976D5;
    display: block;
    clear: both;
    :hover,:active{
      filter: brightness(115%);
    }
  }
`;
```

I don't know if it's possible to remove this background, it only appears when it's mobile
when clicking

problem :

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Touch screen devices don't have mouse events, specifically.  There are actually touch events especially for them.  But it's a common thing to want touch events to utilise mouse events.  I find that mouseenter and mouseleave don't work as well as `mouseover` and `mouseout`.  I think those will solve your problem in this case.

```
<h3 onMouseOver={() => setHover(true)} onMouseOut={() => setHover(false)}>
```

List of DOM events: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_event.asp

Comment: thanks, but i believe the problem is not this it occurs on click i already tested on applying effect with the mouseover and it doesn't work on mobile devices.

Comment: On mobile devices you will have to click (mouse over) and click outside (mouse out). There is no hover on a touch screen. Did you not get this behavior when you tried it?